# Functions preserving almost disjoint of partitions

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, infinite-combinatorics

A collection $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \omega^\omega$
is  *almost disjoint*  iff
$\bigcap_{X\in \mathcal{A}}X^{-1}(j)$ is finite for all $j\in\omega$.

A function $\Gamma:2^\omega\rightarrow 2^\omega$ is 
 *almost-disjoint preserving*  if
$\Gamma(P)$ is almost-disjoint whenever
  $P\subseteq 2^\omega$ is.

If a somewhat regular function (say Borel)
  $\Gamma:2^\omega\rightarrow 2^\omega$
  is almost-disjoint preserving,
  then for some large (dense in some clopen set) subset $P$ of $2^\omega$,
  $\Gamma\upharpoonright P$ is a bitwise isomorphism.
  i.e., for all but finitely many $n$, 
  there exists an $\hat{n}$,
  such that $\Gamma(X)(n)$ is determined by $X(\hat{n})$.
  It seems this can be proved by forcing.

> Is there any simple analytic proof?
>      Is there any reference on this kind of subject?

Note that this is the infinite version
of the following observation:
for every function $\Gamma:2^n\rightarrow 2$,
if $\Gamma(V)$ is disjoint (which simply means $\Gamma(V) = \{0,1\}$)
whenever $V\subseteq 2^n$ is disjoint,
then there is an $m<n$
such that $(\forall \sigma\in 2^n) \ \Gamma(\sigma) = \sigma(m)$
or $(\forall \sigma\in 2^n)\ \ \Gamma(\sigma) = 1-\sigma(m)$.

Thanks in advance~

Comment: it sounds like it has some connections with homomorphisms/automorphisms of $P(\omega)/fin$ (the bitwise isomorphism as you called it is related to the notion of  triviality), for example in Chapter IV of Shelah's proper forcing book

Comment: You might be looking for this paper of Velickovic (Lemma 2 in particular): https://www.jstor.org/stable/2045667?seq=3#metadata_info_tab_contents